# How to fill the image outside a bounding window with some colour

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv

Is it possible to fill the image outside that bounding window with some colour like we do in paint with bucket fill using opencv,python

[image]

Comment: Asking people to follow a random link is pretty much what spammers do. Please rephrase your question. Start by explaining the problem in text form. Move the image link further down, as additional information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use flood fill to do that. You'll first need a mask to segment out the rectangle from your image.

First make a mask to segment out the rectangle. I did it by simple gray threshold. Once you have the mask, fill the roi with image and the rest with the color you want.

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread("face.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

h,w =img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)

ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(gray, 10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.floodFill(thresh2, mask, (350,250), (255,255,0));

thresh2 = cv2.cvtColor(thresh2,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)


thresh2[np.where((thresh2 == [0,0,0]).all(axis = 2))] = [0,255,255]
thresh2[np.where((thresh2 == [255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = img[np.where((thresh2 == [255,255,255]).all(axis=2))]

cv2.imshow("img", thresh2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Well i am trying to do some operations only inside the bounding box ,but this code doesnt actually work for all images,is there any way to do operations like thresholding only inside the bounding box without cropping the image?? I.Newton

Comment: I didnt crop the  image. I did thresholding to get the rectangle. After making mask, you can do the operations as you want. It wont work for all the images because you need to adjust the 10 and (350, 250 ) values accordingly. If You are manually drawing the rectangles, that'd make the job easier.

Comment: thanks i figured a way to draw rectangles around the bounding boxes I.Newton,you gave a gud clue,..

Answer (score 0):

```
ALL CREDITS TO I.NEWTON orwhatever his actual name is..  ;)
     img = cv2.imread(f)
     size=img.shape
     dets1 = detector1(img)    
     for k1, d1 in enumerate(dets1):
         x1=d1.left()
         y1=d1.top()
         w1=d1.right()
         h1=d1.bottom()
         cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(w1,h1),(0,0,0),1)
         cv2.rectangle(img,(0,0),(x1,size[1]),(0,0,0),-1)
         cv2.rectangle(img,(0,0),(size[1],y1),(0,0,0),-1)
         cv2.rectangle(img,(size[1],0),(w1,size[0]),(0,0,0),-1)
         img=cv2.rectangle(img,(size[1],size[0]),(0,h1),(0,0,0),-1)
    cv2.imshow("img", thresh2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: dets1 is the object detector i trained using svm and dlib's code for object detection